# Cannot edit past group 1

Tags: visual-studio-code

On Visual Studio Code, when I split my editor, from group 2 onward, it gets into read only mode.
I have checked for options, shortcuts, extensions that would do this but no luck so far.
thanks.

Comment: Please add more info and screenshot to this question

Comment: @JanČerný  I open VS Code, when on split screen the group 2 (files on the right of the screen) do not allow me to edit, use my arrow keys etc. At the same time if I have I file on group 1 (files on the left side) still allows me to edit those. If I move the same file on group 2 to group 1 I can edit it again.